# Add composite primary key to secondary association table in production

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a table which contained an error on setup:

```
ass_table = Table('ass', db.Model.metadata,
    Column('id1', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('class1.id')),
    Column('id2', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('class2.id')),
)
```

I really should have added `primary_key=True` to both `Columns` or a `PrimaryKeyConstraint('id1', 'id2', name='silly_me')`.

The alembic autogeneration code it created originally was:

```
op.create_table('ass',
    sa.Column('id1', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.Column('id2', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['id2'], ['class2.id'], ),
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['id1'], ['class1.id'], )
)
```

And I confirm my Postgres database does not have a primary key established on the `ass` table.

Adding the code in now does not auto-generate an alembic script to migrate my database.

What is the best course of action to add the necessary composite primary key ***without interrupting or destroying the existing data*** in production?

Comment: I think you can go about specifying both fields as primary key (only) in sqlalchemy model, and it won't impact anything and will let you work through your model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know alembic, but to do this in pure postgres, I would do the following:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CONCURRENTLY silly_me_idx ON ass(id1, id2);
ALTER TABLE ass ADD CONSTRAINT silly_me_pkey PRIMARY KEY USING INDEX silly_me_idx;
```

Comment: can I ask why `ALTER TABLE ass ADD PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2);` would not suffice? Does that lack something other than the explicit naming of the constraint?

Comment: That would work, but it would require an exclusive lock on the table while it builds the index.  Building the index concurrently does not acquire an exclusive lock (but it's slower).  You can then add the PK using that index, which should be nearly instantaneous.